# Preferred way to DB connection in iOS

Tags: mysql, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlconnection

I'm a beginner iOS developer, and I'm trying to build a CRM system to learn the different aspects of developing.

I have a question regarding the preferred way to connect to an external SQL-server. I'm using Karl Krafts' Obj-C MySQL Connector by the way.
Right now I init the Database-controller (which in turn creates, then idles the connection to the server) object in my app delegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions), and that gives me some unwanted side-effects.. The screen is black a long time at startup if connection to the DB is slow, and sometimes the app is "too fast" and the query is trying to execute before the connection has been fully established - resulting in an exception being thrown.

The behavior I want (and guess is the preferred) is that the GUI loads up first, and then the initialization of the DB-controller and connection is established in a background thread - updating the GUI when the data has been acquired.

How would I achieve this? I have tried a number of different ways i've come across in my research, dispatch_queues and initing it straight from the viewDidLoad etc, but none give me the desired "GUI then data"-effect.

Also, would it be preferred to have an idling connection during the session of the program - or should each query 'connect - do its thing - disconnect'?

Regards, Christopher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commandment One: don't do networking on the main thread - it's reserved for the UI. Else your app will have a laggy and frozen UI.

Commandment Two: instead of a lot of sequential synchronous calls, use asynchronous calls (GCD, background threads, etc.), events and callbacks. Cocoa (Touch) is designed with this in mind, so it's easy to do.

Commandment Three: if you launch something automatically, let it be launched when the app is fully ready. Let the call to the web service be the last one in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Even better, let the user have the possibility to initiate the login via a user action, i. e. by pressing a "Login" button.

Commandment Four: read the first three Commandment again and keep them in mind. Practice them until you know them well.

Comment: +1 And if you want to write up a full 10 for iOS development in general, it could be a great resource to link to. "The Cocoa Commandments"

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle Thank you! Good idea. Maybe I'm gonna do that, there are always novices who would appreciate it.

Comment: To be honest I'd appreciate it too. For some of the less intuitive aspects of the language having a one stop resource for a good guideline to follow could be quite beneficial.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!
Unfortionatly I don't have any place for the user to "start" the whole process, I want it to start with the app.. Although when I put the DB-connection init (even in an async dispatch) in the screen is black quite a long time at startup.. How would you do this?

Comment: @ChristopherCarlsson If the screen is black for a while, then you're not using a background thread for real. Do so and it'll be fine.

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of dispatch_async? When I use that in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` the GUI doesn't get updated since it wants to update before the connection is established..

Comment: @ChristopherCarlsson Do you use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);`? If so, that performs the block on the main thread.

Comment: Im using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, (unsigned long) NULL), ^(void)`, is this correct? Thanks for the help by the way, really appreciated!

Comment: @ChristopherCarlsson I'd suggest trying this in a background thread, i. e. using NSThread and see if it changes anything.